# Password Validations using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

function ValidatePassword() {

```
    var rules = [{
            Pattern: "[a-zA-Z]",
            Target: "UpperCase"
        },

        {
            Pattern: "[0-9]",
            Target: "Numbers"
        },
        {
            Pattern: "[!@@#$%^&*]",
            Target: "Symbols"
        }
    ];

    var password = $("#password").val();
    
    $("#Length").removeClass(password.length > 6 ? "fa-times" : "fa-check");
    $("#Length").addClass(password.length > 6 ? "fa-check" : "fa-times");
    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
        $("#" + rules[i].Target).removeClass(new RegExp(rules[i].Pattern).test(password) ?
            "fa-times" :
            "fa-check");
        $("#" +
            rules[i].Target).addClass(new RegExp(rules[i].Pattern).test(password) ? "fa-check" :
            "fa-times");
    }
} 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#password").on('onkeypress', ValidatePassword)

});
```

Validations not work according to rules and pattern ..... and i am using the onkrypress and these validations shows when page is reload..

Comment: <input onkeypress="ValidatePassword()"  />
               <ul class="error-list">
                    <li><i id="Length" class="fas fa-times fa-check"></i>At least 8 characters</li>
                    <li><i id="Symbols" class="fas fa-times fa-check"></i>Contain at least 1 symbol
         </li>
                    <li><i id="Numbers" class="fas fa-times fa-check"></i>Contain at least 1 number
                    </li>
                    <li><i id="UpperCase" class="fas fa-times fa-check"></i>Combine uppercase and
                        lowercase letters</li>
                </ul>

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.on()` you should define your event without 'on' keyword
replace `onkeypress` with `keypress`

```js
$("#password").on('keypress', ValidatePassword)
```

or:

```js
$("#password").keypress(ValidatePassword)
```

Comment: not work in this way